# How to I compress a tarball with gzip?

Tags: c++, linux, gzip, tar, zlib

Hey, I was wondering if anyone knew how I could compress a tarball file with gzip. I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813223/how-to-compress-a-directory-with-libbz2-in-c) already and compressed a tarball successfully, although I want to then compress that tarball with gzip instead of libbz2.

I have also tried implementing the `gztack` function from the `gzappend.c` example from the [zlib source code.](http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz) but ended up getting a bunch of errors and deprecating warnings, so I figured I won't get much out of a deprecated example.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, preferably with the zlib library?

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this is to pass the `z` option to `tar` when you create the tar file. What's your motivation for wanting to do this in C++?

Comment: My motivation is that I want this to be cross platform and usually on other platforms they won't have tar installed in the system.

Comment: which linux platforms do not have tar?

Comment: Not sure, I just put linux as a tag because that is what I am currently working with, I will probably use Windows/Mac in the future. It just doesn't seem right using a system call, even if you are sure MOST of the platforms you are developing it for should have it.

Comment: @Sam Back in the bronze age some of the one- and two-floppy systems didn't have gnutar and you had to zip them separately. Aside from that I haven't a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) routines `gzopen` to open a compressed stream, `gcwrite` to write data to it and compress it, and `gzclose` to close it.  Here's a complete program that compresses one file to another:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argc < 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input output\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Open input & output files
  FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  if(input == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "fopen: %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  gzFile output = gzopen(argv[2], "wb");
  if(output == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "gzopen: %s: %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
    fclose(input);
    return 1;
  }

  // Read in data from the input file, and compress & write it to the
  // output file
  char buffer[8192];
  int N;
  while((N = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), input)) > 0)
  {
    gzwrite(output, buffer, N);
  }

  fclose(input);
  gzclose(output);

  return 0;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$ ./mygzip input output.gz
$ diff input <(gunzip < output.gz)  # Verify that it worked
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply using zlib?  There's a tutorial here:
http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

That's a good way to make a gzip file, certainly.  By your stated goals I would assume that using `popen()` or `system()` to run a program is not so great (requires the machine to have something else installed, not to mention it's less efficient if you're going to do this a lot).

Answer (score 0):

There's a clear way to do this in the shell:

```
gzip ball.tar
```

You can have the C++ program uses the `popen` system call to run the command.

You can also write a wrapper to zlib that emulates c++ iostream (for example http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/)

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a const char* argument string for the `tar` command and passing it into the [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) function in `cstdlib.h` is probably the simplest way to do that. Or using popen(), as Foo Bah's answer mentioned. I find it hard to believe that your target platforms include ones without `tar` or `gzip`, as even recovery shells like BusyBox have access to `tar`. Once system()/popen() returns (check the return code for success obviously), create an [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) to the compressed file and do whatever you like with it.

EDIT: When you tag something Linux people tend to assume that means specifically and only Linux. Of course `tar` will not work for standard installs of Windows operating systems, so in that case, yes, provide a bundled zlib dll and use zlib as John mentions.