# How compress data in memory buffer by using libbz2 library in C program

Tags: c, compression

I try to compress memory data by using libbz2 library in C program.

Should I use this function of libbz2?:

```
int BZ2_bzCompress ( bz_stream *strm, int action );
```

Can anyone show me an example?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compress a directory with libbz2 in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813223/how-to-compress-a-directory-with-libbz2-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/html/util-fns.html

Use `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress()` and `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress()` for simple paired compress/decompress.

This page describes the meaning of the last 3 parms:
http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/html/low-level.html

Comment: How do I know the compress/decompress size so I can allocate the buffers properly?

Comment: @karliwson, you can't... Either this information is already known (you have it previously stored, such as you stored the initial buffer length elsewhere), or you over-allocate. For decompression, the latter is nearly impossible.